# Hostgater shared hosting cpu usage problems

Tags: wordpress, joomla, hosting, shared

I have shared webhosting and sometimes i go over the max allowed cpu usage once a day, sometimes two or three times. but i cant really narrow it down to anything specific.

I have the following scripts installed:

wordpress joomla owncloud dokuwiki fengoffice

before i was just running joomla on this hosting package and everything was fine, but i upgraded to have more domains available and also hosted other scripts. now like wordpress, owncloud and so on.

but no site has high traffic or hits. most of the stuff is anyway only used by me.

i talked to the hostgator support team and they told me there is a ssh command to monitor or watch the server and see whats causing the problem.

the high cpu load just happesn for a very short peak, because everytime i check the percentage of cpu usage in the cpanel its super low. the graph shows me the spike, but it looks worse than it really is, because the graph gets updated only every hour, and that makes it hard to narrow it down...

i am new to all this. can somebody help me to figure this out?

BTW:

I hope this question is fine now here, kinda dont really understand this plattform yet...

Comment: You are paying for hosting therefore you should pursue this issue with the Hostgator support team. That's what they are there for. They have already mentioned that you can monitor traffic on the server using SSH, not sure if you have already done this but if so, let them know and they will most likely give you more instructions. To be honest, I personally despise cheap hosts as there is always a catch such as low server requests etc. If you have a server with multiple CMS's, then you should consider using a host that specializes in CMS hosting like Siteground

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, well i talked many times to the tech support from hostgator, but they dont really want to help me with this problem. also they dont give any ssh support. Thtas all on me, even on shared server, which is more likely rented by not so tech savy users... I guess I will try to get my own server and see how that works...

Answer (score 0):

Just so you have more information, I to host many websites with HostGator using a reseller/shared account.  The performance of your site is most likely not an issue, and is related more to HostGator's new servers and it's poor MySQL performance.  None of my WordPress sites had issues for years, despite high traffic/plugins etc.  Fast forward to late 2013 after EIG purchased HostGator (and others like BlueHost) and the performance on the "new more powerful" servers is anything but.  Limits on CPU and processes are more aggressive, and while outright downtime isn't an issue, the performance during peak hours is exceedingly poor.  Sites which rely on MySQL databases all suffer from poor performance and no amount of caching or plugin optimization will help (I should know as I spent months reviewing my sites trying many optimizations).

My advice:  Find another web host and/or upgrade your hosting to a VPS that can scale based on your needs.

I moved my higher traffic/important clients to WPEngine.  The speed difference and quality support is massive.

Comment: Thanks, I was already thinking about that and thats what hostgator told me too, but well they ofcourse tell you this, just to sell more expensive servers ;) I guess i found a good hoster and its also a full root server. I will try my luck :) cant get any worse ;)